# After iot-core auto-update to 10.0.14393.67 cannot access iot-hub/Azure from Headless UWP app -- > now broken

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I have an RPi2 iot-core app which has run fine for months on the previous iot-core os release. I access it regularly via the iot-hub and it writes to Azure blobs ... until the automatic update last week to version 10.0.14393.67 at which time my UWP-headless-app, although still running (I see this in my reference version via the local device portal app), no longer communicates with iot-hub or azure.

Any ideas what going on and what can I do without having to start from scratch?

Comment: That's interesting. Have you debugged to see which line of code fails?

Comment: Are you sure its the OS update that's caused this? Could be a red hering. If you get the IoT Hub 'Device Explorer' app from CodePlex and connect to your hub it tells you the devices last connection date/time on the management tab. Is that just after the OS update?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I wish it were a red herring, but it is not. It happened on my lab/QA devices at the same time. Using the local portal, I could check those devices to see what had changed. The only change was that I had a new OS version. My app was still active and running after the reboot, but it would no longer take messages from iot-hub (device explorer) and was no longer sending data to the azure blob. This app has been fine on all machines for months until the os update, where it then broke on all at the same time.

Comment: Looks like someone else had this same problem earlier that I didn't have since my device was not yet in the field: http://developers.de/blogs/indraneel/archive/2016/04/22/how-to-disable-the-auto-update-on-windows-10-iot-core.aspx

Comment: @Jackie: When I attach the debugger to the blocked device from VStudion 2015.3 in our QA/Lab, it  blocks: the debugger attaches without errors, but then hangs and shows no output. When I deploy my uwp-app anew in debug mode, everything works perfectly, since everything is redeployed and restarted from scratch: there are no more errors - identical code. This procedure won't work for devices in the field of course.

Comment: @GGleGrand,Have you updated your "Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP" reference to the latest version?

Comment: @Jackie: VS2015.3 installed but references show 10.0.10586.0\. Now referencing library 10.0.14393.0 from VStudio. This is independent of initial problem though....

Comment: Please note that it was the auto-update to existing deployments that caused my outage. If I recompile and redeploy using the new version, all is fine, but I can only do this with local devices . I usually update my app via the network, but since the update caused all network coms to my UWP app go down, I am stuck.